# JSoup always timing out

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to work with JSoup to parse an HTML file I have generated through Servlet. From what I have read, I need to declare a Document. When I run the code

> Document doc= Jsoup.parse(URL, 10000);

It always times out, if i increase the timeout time, it will run until it reaches that time. When i put in `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it simply runs forever. I am working in Google Chrome on a macbook pro.

My questions are:

Is this just my computer or am i doing something wrong?

Is there a way to fix this or a way to parse the HTML page that is entirely differently?

Comment: Please post what is link give a little detail...

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative Solutions**

As explained in the documentation of Jsoup if you have an accessible URL than you can get its content this way:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
```

If you have HTML in a string this is how you should parse it:

```
document = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
```

If you have HTML in a local file then:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("FilePath"), "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
```

**Your Solution**
The way you are using Jsoup parser is correct but problem is with `link` perhaps if you can provide details about it then we can figure out what's going wrong.

Make sure whatever HTML is generated by your Servlet is accessible if it is the `link`of yours should be a `URL` to that Servlet.

Comment: the first one didnt work, and my html is generated in the program so there is no string and no file

Comment: lets see, the servlet that generates output, does it map to some URL, like http://localhost:8084/yourproject/someservletcall?If yes the you must use this url, can you share what `link`in your code is?